# Why doesn't JSON.stringify display object properties that are functions?

Tags: javascript, json, function, object, stringify

Why doesn't JSON.stringify() display prop2?

```
var newObj = {
  prop1: true,
  prop2: function(){
    return "hello";
  },
  prop3: false
};

alert( JSON.stringify( newObj ) ); // prop2 appears to be missing

alert( newObj.prop2() ); // prop2 returns "hello"

for (var member in newObj) {
    alert( member + "=" + newObj[member] ); // shows prop1, prop2, prop3
}
```

JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/egret230/efGgT/

Comment: @BrandtSolovij: Functions are objects: try running `(function() {}) instanceof Object`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because [JSON](https://json.org) cannot store functions. According to the spec, a value must be one of:

[image: Valid JSON values]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/value.gif))</sub>

---

As a side note, this code will make the functions noticed by `JSON.stringify`:

```
Function.prototype.toJSON = function() { return "Unstorable function" }
```

Comment: So in this case, JSON can't store `undefined`?

Comment: @Derek: Correct. I think `JSON.stringify` converts it to `null`

Comment: @Derek: `JSON.stringify` omits members with `undefined` values.  A variable set to `undefined` is indistinguishable from one that was never set at all.

Comment: @apsillers: ...at least from JSON view. Setting a property to undefined will create the property.

Comment: `Function.prototype.toJSON` Nice one!

Comment: @Berji: Yes, sorry, that's an important disinction.  At JSON level they're indistinguishable; at a language level they're not.

Comment: As to *why* `Function.prototype.toJSON`, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) explains it well.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way with using a .prototype. You can add an function to stringify

```
JSON.stringify(obj, function(k, v) {
  if (typeof v === 'function') {
    return v + '';
  }
  return v;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not supposed to stringify methods (or any functions) - especially since most methods of built in objects (and thus the prototypes of any user-defined objects) are native code.

If you *really* need it to print your methods out, you can override your object's .toString method, but when you call JSON.parse on the stringified output, it will treat the method as if it were just a string, and to be able to call it as a function you'd have to `eval` it - a practice that is typically not recommended.