# JavaScript DEEP stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, stringify

I'm having a problem getting the right result when "stingifying" a complex JSON object.
for example:

```
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": [
    [
      {
        "c": "c",
        "d": "d",
        "e": "e"
      },
      {
        "c": "c",
        "d": "d",
        "e": "e"
      },
      {
        "c": "c",
        "d": "d",
        "e": "e"
      }
    ],
    [{
        "c": "c",
        "d": "d",
        "e": "e"
      }],
    [
      {
        "c": "c",
        "d": "d",
        "e": "e"
      },
      {
        "c": "c",
        "d": "d",
        "e": "e"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "f": [
    {
      "g": "g",
      "h": "h"
    },
    {
      "g": "g",
      "h": "h"
    },
    {"g": "g"}
  ]
}
```

In the example above, `a` and even `f` stringify great but i'm "loosing" the content of the value of `b` (stringify as empty array), From what i read if there is more then one level deep in the JSON there is a need to do a deep stringify but i can not seem to get it the right way to see the content of the `b` key.

Any one have any idea on how to do that?

p.s. the nodes can have even 3 or more levels deep, not just one or two.

Thank you

Update: I've found the problem, I am using $.tmpl and for some reason, in some cases i am getting something like associative array instead of array of objects (I know there is no such thing as associative array in JS but that is what i am getting, array of size 0 with key-value pairs inside it, NOT AN OBJECT) in the value of "b" in the second level. Stringify is doing what I expected it to do now. Thanks

Comment: I don't know where you read that. `JSON.stringify` should process all levels. Can you show what you're getting and point out where you're losing something?

Comment: What are values of a, c, d, e, g and h before this assignment?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/kEf82/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see: [Why doesn't JSON.stringify display object properties that are functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729258/why-doesnt-json-stringify-display-object-properties-that-are-functions) there is a diagram in the answer showing which values are allowed. "undefined" is not one of them. As also stated in the comments there, `undefined` values will be omited when using stringify.

Comment: Thank you, you made me examine the code and results again and I've found the problem (wrote about it in the update), now i just need to find why it happens. 10x