# How to resolve incorrect return result from Ramda reduce function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reduce, ramda.js

I have a data structure I call a 'spec' which looks like this:

```
const spec = {
  command: {
    name: 'name',
    description: 'description',
    alias: 'alias',
    arguments: '_children/Arguments'
  },
  arguments: {
    name: 'name',
    alias: 'alias',
    optional: 'optional',
    description: 'description'
  }
};
```

So the elements inside of **command** and **arguments** are properties mapped to paths. The best illustration of this is **spec.command.arguments**. What I need to do is translate this into another object with the same shape, but the paths are converted into Ramda lenses (using R.lensPath).

So conceptually, this is translated into something like this:

```
const spec = {
  command: {
    name: lens('name'),
    description: lens('description'),
    alias: lens('alias'),
    arguments: lens('_children/Arguments')
  },
  arguments: {
    name: lens('name'),
    alias: lens('alias'),
    optional: lens('optional'),
    description: lens('description')
  }
};
```

The above is not meant to be taken literally, it is a pseudo structure. For example **lens('_children/Arguments')** just represents a lens built using Ramda lensPath.

So here is my code:

```
const spec = {
  command: {
    name: 'name',
    description: 'description',
    alias: 'alias',
    arguments: '_children/Arguments'
  },
  arguments: {
    name: 'name',
    alias: 'alias',
    optional: 'optional',
    description: 'description'
  }
};

function lensify (spec) {
  const result = R.pipe(
    R.toPairs,
    R.reduce((acc, pair) => {
      const field = pair[0];
      const path = pair[1];
      const lens = R.compose(
        R.lensPath,
        R.split('/')
      )(path);

      acc[field] = lens; // Is there something wrong with this, if so what?
      return acc;
    }, { dummy: '***' }) // list of pairs passed as last param here
  )(spec);

  // The following log should show entries for 'name', 'description', 'alias' ...
  console.log(`+++ lensify RESULT: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
  return result;
}

function makeLenses (spec) {
  const result = {
    command: lensify(spec.command),
    arguments: lensify(spec.arguments)
  };

  return result;
}

makeLenses(spec);
```

The key point of failure I think is inside the reducer function, which returns the updated accumulator (*acc[field] = lens;*). For some reason which I can't understand, this assignment is being lost, and the accumulator is not being correctly populated on each iteration. As you can see from the code sample, the initial value passed into reduce is an object with a single *dummy* property. The result of the reduce is incorrectly just this single dummy value and not all the fields with their respective Ramda lenses.

However, what's really gonna bake your noodle is that the exact same code running in Ramda repl exhibits different behaviour, see this code in the repl at: [Ramda code](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20spec%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20command%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27name%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20description%3A%20%27description%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20alias%3A%20%27alias%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20arguments%3A%20%27_children%2FArguments%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20arguments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27name%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20alias%3A%20%27alias%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20optional%3A%20%27optional%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20description%3A%20%27description%27%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20lensify%20%28spec%29%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.toPairs%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.reduce%28%28acc%2C%20pair%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20field%20%3D%20pair%5B0%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20path%20%3D%20pair%5B1%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20lens%20%3D%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.lensPath%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.split%28%27%2F%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%28path%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20acc%5Bfield%5D%20%3D%20lens%3B%20%2F%2F%20Is%20there%20something%20wrong%20with%20this%2C%20if%20so%20what%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20acc%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20dummy%3A%20%27%2A%2A%2A%27%20%7D%29%20%2F%2F%20list%20of%20pairs%20passed%20as%20last%20param%20here%0A%20%20%29%28spec%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20The%20following%20log%20should%20show%20entries%20for%20%27name%27%2C%20%27description%27%2C%20%27alias%27%20...%0A%20%20console.log%28%60%2B%2B%2B%20lensify%20RESULT%3A%20%24%7BJSON.stringify%28result%29%7D%60%29%3B%0A%20%20return%20result%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20makeLenses%20%28spec%29%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20command%3A%20lensify%28spec.command%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20arguments%3A%20lensify%28spec.arguments%29%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20return%20result%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AmakeLenses%28spec%29%3B%0A%0A)

I'm running node version 10.13.0

The result that the Repl code produces is this:

```
{
  'arguments': {
    'alias': function (r) {
      return function (e) {
        return z(function (t) {
          return n(t, e)
        }, r(t(e)))
      }
    },
    'description': function (r) {
      return function (e) {
        return z(function (t) {
          return n(t, e)
        }, r(t(e)))
      }
    },
    'dummy': '***',
    'name': function (r) {
      return function (e) {
        return z(function (t) {
          return n(t, e)
        }, r(t(e)))
      }
    },
    'optional': function (r) {
      return function (e) {
        return z(function (t) {
          return n(t, e)
        }, r(t(e)))
      }
    }
  },
  'command': {
    'alias': function (r) {
      return function (e) {
        return z(function (t) {
          return n(t, e)
        }, r(t(e)))
      }
    },
    'arguments': function (r) {
      return function (e) {
        return z(function (t) {
          return n(t, e)
        }, r(t(e)))
      }
    },
    'description': function (r) {
      return function (e) {
        return z(function (t) {
          return n(t, e)
        }, r(t(e)))
      }
    },
    'dummy': '***',
    'name': function (r) {
      return function (e) {
        return z(function (t) {
          return n(t, e)
        }, r(t(e)))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the result looks a bit complicated because the values of each property is the lens created by lensProp.

This is in contrast to the following (note that order of command and arguments is reversed, but this shouldn't be significant):

```
{
  'command': {
    'dummy': '***'
  },
  'arguments': {
    'dummy': '***'
  }
}
```

which is being returned in my unit test.

I've wasted about 2 days on this and have now admitted defeat, so hopefully, somebody can shed some light on this. Cheers.

Comment: I'm really not sure what your question is here.  The results in the REPL look correct to me.  (Note that `JSON.stringify` won't give you useful results on function properties.)  You return an object with `arguments` and `command` properties, each of which is an object containing `name`, `alias` `arguments` and `optional` properties, each holding a lens.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: But as I say, whats running in my unit test is not the same as the repl. The last JSON representation is different to the representation returned in the repl. The code in my unit test was cut and pasted un-modified into Repl. When the code in my test was not working, I tried it in the Repl and was surprised at the different result.

Comment: Note that, as long as you don't actually *want* that `dummy` property, you can write `lensify` much more simply as `const lensify = map(pipe(split('/'), lensPath))`.

Comment: mmm, that's an interesting proposition, I'll try that. But the problem I have is the same code running in 2 different contexts giving different results

Comment: Your final REPL result is not wrapped in `JSON.stringify`.  It uses the REPL's more sophisticated display feature.  `JSON.stringify(makeLenses(spec)) //=> "{\"command\":{\"dummy\":\"***\"},\"arguments\":{\"dummy\":\"***\"}}"`

Comment: So, what do you mean by different results?  The stringified result of your output object has little to do with its behavior.  Have you actually applied your spec to real data?  And how do you plan on doing it?

Comment: Also, you can skip `lensify` altogether with `const makeLenses = map(map(pipe(split('/'), lensPath)))`, assuming that you want to apply it to all elements of your spec.

Comment: Yeah I have applied it to real data. Thats how I discovered the problem. The client code couldn't access the lenses because they were missing from the result of makeLenses. But I'll try your more compact version. I'm still not getting something though and it would be nice to find out what's going wrong. The output that I quoted, is produced by the same code, ie: console.log(`+++ lensify RESULT: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`); Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Can you share some simplified test data and the code you use to apply that spec to the data?  What you have generated looks right to me in the REPL, but without any way to test it, I can't tell what might be going wrong.

Comment: Ok will do in a bit, I need a break. My head is hurting!

Comment: Actually, I realised I made a big boo boo in some of my client code, which is responsible for the undefined I was seeing trying to access the lenses. It work now and produces the same result as the Repl. Thanks for you help Scott. I'll use your much more streamlined version in my final code, although I already knew I was going to streamline it. One thing I wasnt aware of though was the enhanced display abilities of the repl, which is what confused me. The console.log/JSON.stringify statement I was using was not showing the lens properties that the Repl does, which sent me down a rabbit hole!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows the simplest usage of your output I can imagine, mapping `view` on the lenses against a common object.  It seems to work properly both in the REPL, here in a snippet, and in Node 10.13.0:

```js
const {map, pipe, split, lensPath, view} = ramda  

const makeLenses = map ( map ( pipe ( split ('/'), lensPath )))

const applyLensSpec = (lensSpec) => (obj) => 
  map ( map ( f => view (f, obj) ), lensSpec)

const spec = {command: {name: "name", description: "description", alias: "alias", arguments: "_children/Arguments"}, arguments: {name: "name", alias: "alias", optional: "optional", description: "description"}};

const myTransform = applyLensSpec(
  makeLenses(spec),
)

const testObj =   {
  name: 'foo', 
  alias: 'bar', 
  description: 'baz', 
  optional: false, 
  _children: {
    Arguments: ['qux', 'corge']
  }
}

console .log (
  myTransform (testObj)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script>
```

Comment: Thats great Scott, cheers. My problem was 2 two fold, incorrect client code that was not shown in this post and confusion about JSON.stringify and how this can be different to Ramda repl

Comment: The REPL tries to be more helpful than `JSON.stringify`.  This is the first time I've heard of confusion caused by that, but I can certainly understand how it might happen!

Comment: Well I'm sure in the fullness of time and more acquired knowledge, I'm sure it\ll turn out that I misunderstood something or did something wrong. It all part of my javascript journey. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An addendum to this post and to conform what Scott said, the reason for this post is the deficiency on JSON.stringify and this is in fact the moral of this story; do not always trust the output of JSON.stringify. Here is a test case that confirms this:

```
  context('JSON.stringify', () => {
    it.only('spec/lensSpec', () => {
      const spec = {
        command: {
          name: 'name',
          description: 'description',
          alias: 'alias',
          arguments: '_children/Arguments'
        },
        arguments: {
          name: 'name',
          alias: 'alias',
          optional: 'optional',
          description: 'description'
        }
      };

      const makeLensSpec = R.map(R.map(R.pipe(
        R.split('/'),
        R.lensPath
      )));

      const lensSpec = makeLensSpec(spec);
      console.log(`INPUT spec: ${JSON.stringify(spec)}`);
      // The following stringify does not truly reflect the real value of lensSpec.
      // So do not trust the output of JSON.stringify when the value of a property
      // is a function as in this case where they are the result of Ramda.lensProp.
      //
      console.log(`RESULT lensSpec: ${JSON.stringify(lensSpec)}`);
      const rename = {
        'name': 'rename',
        'alias': 'rn',
        'source': 'filesystem-source',
        '_': 'Command',
        'describe': 'Rename albums according to arguments specified.',
        '_children': {
          'Arguments': {
            'with': {
              'name': 'with',
              '_': 'Argument',
              'alias': 'w',
              'optional': 'true',
              'describe': 'replace with'
            },
            'put': {
              'name': 'put',
              '_': 'Argument',
              'alias': 'pu',
              'optional': 'true',
              'describe': 'update existing'
            }
          }
        }
      };

      // NB, if the output of JSON.stringify was indeed correct, then this following
      // line would not work; ie accessing lensSpec.command would result in undefined,
      // but this is not the case; the lensSpec can be used to correctly retrieve the
      // command name.
      //
      const name = R.view(lensSpec.command.name, rename);
      console.log(`COMMAND name: ${name}`);
    });
  });
```

The log statements of note are:

> console.log(`INPUT spec: ${JSON.stringify(spec)}`);

which displays this:

```
INPUT spec: {"command":{"name":"name","description":"description","alias":"alias","arguments":"_children/Arguments"},"arguments":{"name":"name","alias":"alias","optional":"optional","description":"description"}}
```

> console.log(`RESULT lensSpec: ${JSON.stringify(lensSpec)}`);

This is the one at fault (lensSpec contains properties whose values are functions which stringify can't display, so misses them out entirely, giving an incorrect representation:

```
RESULT lensSpec: {"command":{},"arguments":{}}
```

> console.log(`COMMAND name: ${name}`);

This works as expected:

```
COMMAND name: rename
```

NB: I just found this: [Why doesn't JSON.stringify display object properties that are functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729258/why-doesnt-json-stringify-display-object-properties-that-are-functions)